# Using Firebase Authentication UID in Firestore for document ID causing problems in website

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

On my website, I have a table with a list of all my users where I can edit their profile.

The trouble I am having is only some users will allow me to edit their details. I noticed the problem only happens to the user's whos Document ID in my Firestore begin with a number, for example
**4lbkdHe2hIRmM9Z6IIQTtndbmH23**. Other users that have a letter at the start of their ID work fine. The Document IDs are generated from the UID in Authentication.

To edit a user an onclick function is called that contains the Document ID of that table row. I have tried making the ID a string but no luck.

**Code for the table to be created.**

```
function getAllUser(){
var docRef = db.collection("users");
docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

   html = createJobRow(doc.data(),doc.id);
    $('.jobsTable').find('tbody').append(html);

});
jobsDataTable = $('.jobsTable').DataTable({"order": [[ 1, "desc" ]], language: { search: "", searchPlaceholder: "Search...", sLengthMenu: "_MENU_" }, "lengthMenu": [[30, 50, 100, -1], [30, 50, 100, "All"]] });
  });
 }

function createJobRow(user,id)
{
if(user['role']=='user' )
{

// var user_id = id.toString();

html = '<tr id="'+id+'">';
html += '  <td class="centercheck"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox selectitem" name="selectitem" id="selectitem" value="'+id+'"/></td>'; 
html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+id+'</td>';
html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+user['name']+'</td>';
html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+user['company']+'</td>';
html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+user['email']+'</td>';
html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+user['trade']+'</td>';
html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+user['isApproved']+'</td>';
html += '<td class="centercheck"><button type="button" onclick="editInvoice('+id+')" class="btn center-btn"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>';
html += '<button type="button" onclick="editJob('+id+')" class="btn btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></button></td>';
html += '</tr>';
return html;

}
else {
return null;
}

}
```

**Onclick function for Editting Job**

```
function editJob(id,user){


var userID = id;
var tableUser = $(userID).find("td:eq(1)").text();
  console.log(tableUser)
  console.log(userID)
    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(tableUser).get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            showModalData(doc.data(),id);
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
    }
```

**Modal to show user profile**

```
function showModalData(user,id){

    var userID = id;
    var tableUser = $(userID).find("td:eq(1)").text();


       // console.log(user)

    $('#jobForm')[0].reset();
    modal = $('#jobsAddEditModal');
    modal.find('.modal-title').html('Edit Profile');
    modal.find('.submit-btn').html('Update Profile');
    modal.find('#userid').val(tableUser);
    modal.find('#company').val(user['company']);
    modal.find('#email').val(user['email']);
    modal.find('#expo_token').val(user['expo_token']);
    modal.find('#name').val(user['name']);
    modal.find('#trade').val(user['trade']);
    modal.find('#insurancedocs');

    $('#jobsAddEditModal').modal('show');

  }
```

Error in console is **(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

Comment: I have solved the problem will answer the question just incase anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding an ID to my button then adding the document ID to that ID.

```
html += '<button type="button" id="'+id+'" onclick="editJob(this.id)" class="btn btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></button></td>';
```